# Is there a git command to display the commits merged in a branch after a given date?

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out which commit introduced a problem after July 1st. If I run:

```
git log --since 2015-07-01 stable-branch
```

I will see the commits found in `stable-branch` authored after July 1st. But I will not see the commits authored before July 1st and merged after July 1st, although they could very well be the cause of the bug.

For instance, if there is:

```
$ git log --graph --format='%aD %s' 'c7ebf96a9a4a6143b112c8606d5ee346fb800cec^1..c7ebf96a9a4a6143b112c8606d5ee346fb800cec'
* Wed, 8 Jul 2015 15:36:38 +0200 Merge pull request #4862 from SUSE/wip-11874-hammer
* Wed, 3 Jun 2015 13:13:33 +0200 rgw: Do not enclose the Bucket header in quotes
```

Adding `--since 2015-07-01` will only show the merge commit and not the commit itself:

```
$ git log --since 2015-07-01 --graph --format='%aD %s' 'c7ebf96a9a4a6143b112c8606d5ee346fb800cec^1..c7ebf96a9a4a6143b112c8606d5ee346fb800cec'
* Wed, 8 Jul 2015 15:36:38 +0200 Merge pull request #4862 from SUSE/wip-11874-hammer
```

Although the commit was authored June 3rd, it was merged in `stable-branch` after July 1st.

Is there a set of options to `git-log` that would display the commits that were reachable from `stable-branch` after a given date ?

**Update:** the following snippet does exactly what I need. It's kind of difficult to remember though and it would be nice to have a simpler solution.

```
git log --merges --since 2015-09-01 --until 2015-09-11 --format='%H' stable-branch | while read sha1 ; do echo ------------------------------------ ; git log --format='%aD %s' ${sha1}^1..${sha1} ; done
```

Comment: *I'm trying to figure out which commit introduced a problem [...]* Have you heard of [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#B…)?

Comment: isn't any old commit reachable from the `stable-branch` (assuming you don't have orphaned branches)? git doesn't not distinguish between one parent-branch or the other

Comment: Unfortunately there is no convenient way to test the bug so that ```git bisect``` can use that. It's a transient bug, the best kind ;-)